# Manipulating Current_Date

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my SQL query:

```
select id, max(file_uploaded_at) as latest_date, current_date
from employee_imports
where convert(file_uploaded_at) - integer '90'< current_date AND
error_message IS NULL
group by id
order by latest_date DESC
```

I keep getting back values that are older than 90 days though. Do you know why?

Comment: `convert(file_uploaded_at)` looks totally wrong. What data type is `file_uploaded_at`? And `- integer '90'` can be written as `- 90`

Comment: select id, max(file_uploaded_at) as latest_date, current_date
from employee_imports
where file_uploaded_at - INTERVAL 90 DAYS  < current_date AND
error_message IS NULL
group by id
order by latest_date DESC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id, max(file_uploaded_at) as latest_date, current_date
from employee_imports
where current_date - date(file_uploaded_at) <= 90 AND
error_message IS NULL
group by id
order by latest_date DESC
```

This is what I changed my query to and everything appears to work fine.

Thanks anyway guys.